# Join one column of a dataframe with another dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, df1 and df2 as shown below:

**df1:**

```
     Name          Code          Title_num
 0  Title_1        0             TN_1234_4687
 1  Title_2        0             TN_1234_7053
 2  off_1          18301         TN_1234_1915
 3  off_2          18302         TN_1234_7068
 4  off_3          18303         TN_1234_1828
```

**df2:**

```
     A_Code     T_Code
 0  000000086   18301   
 1  000000126   18302   
 2  000001236   18303   
 3  000012346   18938   
 4  000123456   18910   
 5  000123457   18301
```

Where T_code in df2 is the same as Code in df1. I want to join column Title_num in df1 to df2.

For example, if 'T_Code' in df2 matches 'code' in df1, i want the value in column df1['Title_num'] to be joined to df2. If the value does not exist, NaN should be populated.

**Expected output (df2 after join):**

```
    A_Code      T_Code   Title_num
 0  000000086   18301    TN_1234_1915
 1  000000126   18302    TN_1234_7068
 2  000001236   18303    TN_1234_1828
 3  000012346   18938    NaN
 4  000123456   18910    NaN
 5  000123457   18301    TN_1234_1915
```

For this, I renamed column code in df1 to 'T_code' so as to match the name on df2. Then I ran the following code:

```
 df2.merge(df1,on='T-Code',how='left')
```

This gave the following error: 'T_code' # Check for duplicates

Now, one thing to note is in df2, duplicate T_codes will exist while in df1, Code is unique. I want the Title_num values in df2 to be always appear based on the T_code value [Check row 5 of expected output. T_code value is same as row 1].

Do let me know of a method to perform this. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
df2=pd.merge(df2, df1,left_on='T_Code', right_on='Code', how='left')
df2.drop(columns =['Name', 'Code'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this question is already answered 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212020/8333806).

Thanks good luck.